# xsd: same element name, different type (simple and complex)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

i'm trying for some time to write an xsd file to the following case:

```
<Values xsi:type="me:ArrayOfValue">
   <Value xsi:type="xs:int">1</Value>
   <Value xsi:type="xs:string">I'm a string</Value>
   <Value xsi:type="me:Point">
      <X>10.2</X>
      <Y>2.3</y>
   </Value>
<Values/>
```

i have here a combination of **simple type (int, string) and complex (point)**.

if i had only the simple types i know i could easily use the **union** .

so i tried the **choice** option.

problem is, that **i can't use the same name (value) to all the elements**

can someone please help me with this??

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to read, below is a slightly modified XML (it doesn't change the truth of the answer, just makes it easier to read since I wouldn't have to list two XSDs).

```
<Values xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Value xsi:type="xs:int">1</Value>
   <Value xsi:type="xs:string">I'm a string</Value>
   <Value xsi:type="Point">
      <X>10.2</X>
      <Y>2.3</Y>
   </Value>
</Values>
```

This XSD will validate the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:me="urn:tempuri-org" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Values">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Value"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="Point" >
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:element name="X" type="xsd:decimal" />
      <xsd:element name="Y" type="xsd:decimal" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The problem is, so it'll a Value using xsi:type="xs:date", even though you don't want dates. But then this is just a limitation with XSD 1.0.

To constraint the list of allowed xsi:type attributes, you have to move to XSD 1.1 or use Schematron constraints on top of a XSD 1.0 processor.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using your specific type for `int` and `string`, here is a possible solution that validates the following correct XML file (yours has some problems with wellformedness) :

**XML file**

```
<me:Values xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:me="me">
    <me:Value xsi:type="me:int">1</me:Value>
    <me:Value xsi:type="me:string">I'm a string</me:Value>
    <me:Value xsi:type="me:Point">
        <me:X>10.2</me:X>
        <me:Y>2.3</me:Y>
    </me:Value>
</me:Values>
```

**XML Schema that validates it**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="me" xmlns:me="me" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:element name="Values">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="me:Value" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Value" type="me:myType"/>

        <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="myType" mixed="true"/>

        <xs:complexType name="Point" mixed="true">
            <xs:complexContent>
                <xs:extension base="me:myType">
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="X" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        <xs:element name="Y" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    </xs:sequence>                
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="string" mixed="true">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:restriction base="me:myType">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="int" mixed="true">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:restriction base="me:myType">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:union memberTypes="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

**Some explanation**

It only works because I allow mixed content for the abstract type `myType`. It's the only way (to my knowledge) to restrict a complex type to a simple type. Drawback : your `Point` type is mixed content.